# how to cache or preload youtube video in uiwebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube

I have a youtube video that plays in a uiwebview in my app.  The cell signal is not very good in most areas I am using the app.

How can I cache the youtube video for better performance when playing the video?

Comment: With a UIWebView you get very little control over what is actually happening with the content. You might look in to the YouTube Data API to see if you could cache video from there, but I doubt that Google wants you doing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

I start downloading the video file with a NSURLConnection
    I then implement the received data delegate method like the following.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)aData
{
    bytesFetched += aData.length;
    if( bytesFetched > kBytesRequiredBeforeStart && !hasCachedData )        // kBytesRequiredBeforeStart = 160000
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kVideoURLCacheHasDataNotification object:self];
        hasCachedData = YES;
    }
    [self.fileHandle writeData:aData];          // this file handle is not closed until after the video has finished downloading
}
```

**The fileHandle is created like this**

```
- (NSFileHandle *)fileHandle
{
    if( fileHandle == nil )
    {
        NSError             * theError = nil;
        cachedURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@", kTempFileName]] retain];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:[self.cachedURL path] contents:nil attributes:nil];
        fileHandle = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingToURL:self.cachedURL error:&theError] retain];
        if( fileHandle == nil )
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kVideoURLCacheErrorOccuredNotification object:self];
    }
    return fileHandle;
}
```

****I also have a did finish delegate handling method like this****

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if( hasCachedData == NO )
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kVideoURLCacheHasDataNotification object:self];
        hasCachedData = YES;
    }
    hasFinishedCaching = YES;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kVideoURLCacheDidFinishLoadingNotification object:self];
}
```

**I then have a method to observer the notification like the following**

```
- (void)videoURLCacheHasDataNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self.videoController play];
}
```

**where the videoController is an instance of MPMoviePlayerController created like below, cachedURL is the same one defined above.**

```
- (MPMoviePlayerController *)videoController
{
    if( videoController == nil )
    {
        NSURL       * theURL = self.videoURLCache.cachedURL;
        NSLog( @"Video URL = '%@'", theURL );
        videoController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theURL];
        videoController.shouldAutoplay = NO;
        [videoController setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];
        videoController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        videoController.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
        videoController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
        videoController.view.frame = self.videoView.bounds;
        [videoView addSubview:self.videoController.view];
    }
    NSParameterAssert(videoController != nil);
    return videoController;
}
```